# SQL Server: attach database without a log file

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have uninstalled my SQL Server 2019 and installed SQL Server 2022 Express. All my databases are under:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

My new location is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

Attaching a database directly from the old location results in:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBName.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

I then copied the `.mdf` file to the new location. But trying to attach it from the new location, I get a similar error, but for the log file:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\DBName_log.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

I can't copy the log file into the new location because I don't have enough space on my HD.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: *"Any idea?"* Make more space on your storage device. That log file likely isn't very large, 10's of MBs, so if you can't fit it on your storage device, you have next to no space left.

Comment: It is big, no space to duplicate it.

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate it? Why not just *move* it? Why is it so big? Were you using the full recovery model and never backed up your transaction logs?

Comment: It is 160 gb. I have about 15 gb free. Will it move the file?

Comment: A 160GB log file...? When was the last time you did a transaction log backup?

Comment: I am not a db person. I get DBs from other people to do my local development. I have no idea why it is so big.

Comment: Then I would suggest speaking to them; you *need* the transaction log as it seems that whomever that database belongs to hasn't done a log backup in a long time, so there is a lot of data in that file that isn't in the main database file.

Comment: How are you attaching it? From SSMS or using T-SQL It's more straightforward to use T-SQL. You can actually attach a MDF _without_ an LDF as long as everything was committed when the SQL Server was stopped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

SQL Server locks down the data folder with NTFS ACLs.  So you can fix this by taking ownership of the folder and files and granting full control to the other SQL Server instance.

SQL Server disables permissions inheritance on the files, so you need to grant full control to the other SQL instance to each file.  And if you're connected using Windows Integrated Auth, you'll also need to grant yourself full control over the files.

In my test, after granting full control over the mdf and ldf to 'NT Service\MSSQLSERVER' and to my windows user, I was able to run

```
CREATE DATABASE [Foo]
 ON (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Foo.mdf'  ),
    (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Foo_log.ldf' )
for attach
```

from the default instance.
You can also move (not copy) the files without needing additional space.

Comment: It's showing Owner: Administrators, which I am. It also shows MSSQLSERVER has full control.

Comment: Also if I copy the log into new location and try to attach will it read from the new location?

Comment: I'm not sure MSSQLSERVER is the same identity since you uninstalled and reinstalled the default instance.  And you can specify the file locations when you attach a database.

Comment: I am specifying locations, but getting Access denied. can you please explain how to take an ownership of db file and the log?

Comment: See updated answer.  I just ran through this with the help of procmon.  And remember in Windows your membership in Administrators is not active unless you run a process with elevation.